# Does Tridion 2013 Workflow Designer works with Visio 2013 64-bit

Tags: workflow

Does any have tried installing Tridion 2013 workflow designer with Visio 2013 64 bit. We have installed it and in Add-ins window it always show it as inactive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The workflow designer is not supported with 64 bit versions of Visio. As per the documentation, "[Visio Workflow Designer client prerequisites](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3C6BD51E-0EA5-4375-A62C-76855A5B242F)":

### Third-party software components

The Workflow Designer client application requires one of the following products:

- Microsoft Visio 2013 (32-bit), English version
- Microsoft Visio 2010 SP2 (32-bit), English version (deprecated)
- Microsoft Visio 2010 SP1 (32-bit), English version (deprecated)

Comment: THanks David! I read the documentation but just wanted to make sure if other have faced this issue and there is any workaround to this,

Comment: Yes, I come across people with 64 bit versions that can't access the designer all the time. No, there's no workaround other than installing a 32 bit version as far as I know

Answer (score 2):

We have faced the same problem for Visio 2013 64 bit. You have to uninstalled the 64 bit and installed 32 bit.

You can use one of them -

```
Visio 2013 (32-bit), English version
```

or

```
Microsoft Visio 2010 SP2 (32-bit), English version (deprecated)
```

Or

```
Microsoft Visio 2010 SP1 (32-bit), English version (deprecated)
```

For detail you can log a ticket to SDL support team.

Comment: I had a similar problem and installing 32-bit Visio required uninstalling the whole 64-bit Office. What I did at the end was: keep 64-bit Office 2013 and install Visio 2010 32-bit. Hope this helps.